# Inconsistent results when testing speeds of append and concatenate

Tags: list, python-3.x

I am using Python 3.5.2. I was testing a function that would read words from a file and make them into a list. I made two versions: one with the append method and the other with the concatenate operation. Then, I made another function to test the time they take.

```
import time

def build1(path):
    seq = []
    fin = open(path)
    for line in fin:
        word = line.strip()
        seq.append(word)
    fin.close()
    return seq

def build2(path):
    seq = []
    fin = open(path)
    for line in fin:
        word = line.strip()
        seq += [word]
    fin.close()
    return seq

def test(f, p):
    start = time.time()
    f(p)
    stop = time.time()
    print('Duration: %fs' %(stop - start))

path = 'C:/Users/neem/Desktop/words.txt'
test(build1, path)
test(build2, path)
```

I tested it a few times and here is my output.

```
C:\Users\neem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32>python Programs/Test.py
Duration: 0.171600s
Duration: 0.156000s

C:\Users\neem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32>python Programs/Test.py
Duration: 0.171600s
Duration: 0.202800s

C:\Users\neem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32>python Programs/Test.py
Duration: 0.171600s
Duration: 0.202801s

C:\Users\neem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32>python Programs/Test.py
Duration: 0.171600s
Duration: 0.202800s

C:\Users\neem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32>python Programs/Test.py
Duration: 0.171600s
Duration: 0.187200s

C:\Users\neem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32>python Programs/Test.py
Duration: 0.187200s
Duration: 0.187200s

C:\Users\neem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32>python Programs/Test.py
Duration: 0.187200s
Duration: 0.140400s

C:\Users\neem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32>python Programs/Test.py
Duration: 0.187200s
Duration: 0.187200s

C:\Users\neem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32>python Programs/Test.py
Duration: 0.171600s
Duration: 0.187200s
```

Most of the time, build1 is faster than build2. But sometimes build2 is faster than build1, and sometimes they have equal speed. Why does this happen?

Comment: `with open(path) as f: return f.readlines()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These results **are** pretty much consistent, considering that your CPU is (most probably) doing other things as well. This fact makes your timings irrelevant since you ran each "test code" a single time.

You should use `timeit` to perform these tests. It will run the code many times and output only the few fastest results which will give you a better comparison.

```
def build1():
    seq = []
    fin = open('words.txt')
    for line in fin:
        word = line.strip()
        seq.append(word)
    fin.close()
    return seq

def build2():
    seq = []
    fin = open('words.txt')
    for line in fin:
        word = line.strip()
        seq += [word]
    fin.close()
    return seq


import timeit
print(timeit.Timer(build1).repeat(number=1000))
print(timeit.Timer(build2).repeat(number=1000))
```

This runs `build1` and `build2` 1000 times and returns the 3 best for each function. These results are more consistent than those you saw, with `build1` being faster than `build2` almost always. I've used a text file with 1024 lines for these tests.

```
[0.538437745654897, 0.5233988257550134, 0.523436147804647]
[0.5738405088861467, 0.5879328483021968, 0.574590215558163]
```

Let's time the correct way to do it:

```
def fast():
    with open('words.txt') as f:
        return [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

import timeit
print(timeit.Timer(fast).repeat(number=1000))
>> [0.48617474650164105, 0.46462499504316523, 0.45692032442191644]
```